# What are the gold coins for in Farming Simulator 2015?

Tags: farming-simulator-2015

I've heard about gold coins in Farming Simulator 15 but I have no idea what they are for. Does anyone know what they are for and how I get them?

Comment: A quick Google search brings up the following guide as the top 4 search results, and seems to be a guide to all 100 coins: http://guides.gamepressure.com/farmingsimulator2015/guide.asp?ID=27327

Answer (score 3):

Gold Coins are used as an in game collectible, on the Bjornholm map. According to the [farming simulator wiki](http://farmingsimulator.wikia.com/wiki/Gold_Coins_(Farming_Simulator_15)), collecting all 100 coins, and throwing them down a well, rewards the player with "200,000 litres of each commodity".

Coronus has provided a link to a [gamepressure guide](http://guides.gamepressure.com/farmingsimulator2015/guide.asp?ID=27327), where all the coins are plotted out on a map, and detailed further for the purpose of collection.